# Dock an element with ScrollView when it reaches the top of screen

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, frontend, scrollview

Take the following image as an example. The entire screen underneath the header including image crown, person image and text life is a ScrollView. What I want is that what the Text "Tasks" reaches the region of "Life", it stops going up, which makes it look like docking at the top. Also, I hope "Tasks" could be a button, so we could always skip back to the task list as soon as we tap it.

Thus, what element should I use in SwiftUI to achieve so?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a LazyVStack inside the scroll view you can implement a section with a header for the crown, text and person icon ( those 3 will be in an HStack) and after that the lazy stacks have a parameter called pinnedViews where you will put .sectionHeaders. That should pin the HStack to the top when you scroll up.

```
var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack(pinnedViews: .sectionHeaders) {
                    Section(header:
                                HStack {
                        Button(action: { }) {
                            Text("Crown")
                                .foregroundColor(contentSelection == .one ? .black : .gray)
                        }
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button(action: { }) {
                            Text("Life")
                                .foregroundColor(contentSelection == .two ? .black : .gray)
                        }
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button(action: { }) {
                            Text("Person")
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.green)
                            
                    ) {
                        VStack {
                            ForEach((1...50), id: \.self) { item in
                                ZStack {
                                    Text("This is item number \(item)")
                                }
                                .frame(height: 80)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample code for this solution?